# .htaccess language redirect with exclusion

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

For a multi-langue site I have used the following code to automatically redirect people to the right page. This works great, but does not include stylesheets and other files.

The following code in .htaccess turns www.site.com to www.site.com/fr if a visitor is from France. But it also redirects stylesheet and other files.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(nl.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/nl/.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /nl/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(fr.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/fr/.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /fr/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

www.site.com/css/style.css turns into www.site.com/fr/css/style.css which doesn’t exist
www.site.com/js/file.js turns into www.site.com/fr/js/file.js which doesn’t exist

Is there a way to create an auto redirect, but exclude whole subdirectories? For example, exclude /css/*.* and /js/*.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

so that requests to files and directories that exist will not be rewritten

Comment: Thank you. What will this do to www.site.com/directory/page.php because it does exist and if someone from france accesses it, it needs to go to www.site.com/fr/directory/page.php

Comment: right, in that case just add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/css/.*)` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/js/.*)`

Comment: This would make the new code would be: RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(fr.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/fr/.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/css/.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/js/.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /fr/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]